# .MTS file player?

Tags: video

I've been searching, and I can't find a good .mts video file player. The first search on google leads to such a player, but it doesn't work properly (at least for me- the sound goes on, while instead of having a video, I either have nothing, or I have only the starting image, but doesn't change while the file plays).
So, can anyone tell help me with that?

Comment: MTS files use the MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 video codecs. (And Dolby AC3 for sound). Searching for any video-player which supports those formats can help.

Comment: Have you tried VLC?

Comment: Yes, I have, and doesn't work. VLC ends in only showing one image with the sound going on. I eventually converted the file into a .mkv